# How to add multiple UITapGestureRecognizer for different parts of uiview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Say, I have an UIView of width 100

Is it possible to add 2 gesture recognizers like this:

rightTapGesture for the right side 50 of the view and 
leftTapGesture for the other 50 of the view?

I cant use tabbed buttons though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    switch gestureRecognizer {
    case leftTapGesture:
        return touch.locationInView(theView).x < 50
    case rightTapGesture:
        return touch.locationInView(theView).x >= 50
    default:
        // cannot be here
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call this function in viewDidLoad

Comment: this is connected to the gesture and called on tap, you never call this directly